# how to make a blinking image in CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am new to CSS3 and working on a CSS3 code for blinking images. I just need to show an image with it blinking continually. I can't use a GIF image since the images come dynamically.

Comment: You should include what you have tried. You probably need to use JavaScript with timeouts that change the image source. Be sure to pre-load images before playing.

Comment: ohh silly me... @Rameez rami : Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it's very simple... just use a CSS3 animation on opacity of the image

I hope this helps..

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rameezrami/27754r4f/1/ or use following html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Firefox old*/
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
} 

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
/* IE */
@-ms-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
} 
/* Opera and prob css3 final iteration */
@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
} 
.blink-image {
    -moz-animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; /* Webkit */
    -ms-animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; /* IE */
    animation: blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; /* Opera and prob css3 final iteration */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="blink-image" src="http://www.chicagoexcelclasses.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/css31-180x180.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```