# Javascript changing opacity in a while loop not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make an image constantly fade out and fade in, in order to make it "blink". I use two while loops to change element's opacity attribute. Loops change opacity by 10%, and wait for 10ms. First loop works fine, iterates 10 times and moves on, but the second loop changes opacity only once and then iterates indefinetly without affecting opacity. Does anyone know what's wrong and how to fix that?

```
async function blink(){
    var arrow = document.getElementById('downArrow');
    arrow.style.opacity = 1;
    while(window.getComputedStyle(arrow).opacity>0){
        arrow.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        await sleep(10);
        console.log('first loop');
    }
    while(window.getComputedStyle(arrow).opacity<=1){
        arrow.style.opacity += 0.1;
        await sleep(10);
        console.log('second loop');

    }
    blink();
}


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: You don't need JS for this. You can do it simply with css - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667143/how-to-make-a-blinking-image-in-css3

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful, and likely I will end up using this for simplicity's sake. I would still like to know why is my function not working properly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have faced the weird parts of JavaScript ;)

**`arrow.style.opacity` returns a string.**

When you subtract a number from a string, JS converts both of the operands to a number, so e.x `"1" - 0.1` will return number `0.9`:

```js
console.log("1" - 0.1);
```

However, if you try to add something to a string, JS converts both of the operands to a string, so e.x. `"0.1" + 0.1` will return `"0.10.1"`. And that's exactly what is happening in your code.

```js
console.log("0.1" + 0.1);
```

---

To fix this, you need to convert the `opacity` to a number before adding another number to it.

Also, you have a wrong condition in a second loop, it should be `< 1`, not `<= 1`.

Have a look at this:

```js
async function blink(){
    var arrow = document.getElementById('downArrow');
    arrow.style.opacity = 1;
    while(window.getComputedStyle(arrow).opacity > 0){
        arrow.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        await sleep(10);
        console.log('first loop', arrow.style.opacity);
    }
    
    while(window.getComputedStyle(arrow).opacity < 1){ // Here, `< 1`
        arrow.style.opacity = +arrow.style.opacity + 0.1; // Here, `+arrow.style.opacity` converts it to a number
        await sleep(10);
        console.log('second loop', arrow.style.opacity);

    }
    blink();
}


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

blink();
```

```html
<div id="downArrow" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;"></div>
```